# Minecraft Fabric: Overriding vanilla registries

Tags: overriding, registry, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I'm developing a mod for Minecraft 1.18.2 using Fabric. I'd like my mod to **replace** all the **vanilla** birch trees (or whatever) in the game with my **custom** ones (or whatever). To do this, I'm trying to **override** the **vanilla** configured feature `minecraft:birch` to my **custom** configured feature that I've prepared in advance.

> NOTE: birch trees must be **completely replaced** in the game, **not only** during the world generation phase, but also in all other possible game events and situations (e.g. when growing a birch sapling). Therefore, the use of Fabric Biome Modifications API **will not** cover all the necessary game situations.

I've written some code examples, but none of them work. In the error message, Fabric suggests using the `.set()` method instead of the `.register()`, but this method **does not** exist in the `net.minecraft.core.Registry` class (Parchment mappings) or `net.minecraft.util.registry.Registry` class (Yarn mappings). So I have no clue what to do with this information.

Is there any way to solve this problem **without** using **mixins** or **datapacks** (if possible)?

> NOTE: I'm looking for a compact, simple, clear solution, so I don't prioritize the use of **mixins** and **datapacks**. If there are no other ways, then I can use them.

### Vanilla source code

> NOTE: I'm using Minecraft 1.18.2 with Parchment mappings.

```java
package net.minecraft.data.worldgen.features;

// ...

public class TreeFeatures {
    // ...
    public static final Holder<ConfiguredFeature<TreeConfiguration, ?>> BIRCH = FeatureUtils.register("birch", Feature.TREE, TreeFeatures.createBirch().build());
    // ...
}
```

### My code

> NOTE: I'm using Minecraft 1.18.2 with Parchment mappings.

#### Way 1 (according to the vanilla source code)

##### ️ Code

```java
FeatureUtils.register("birch", Feature.TREE, MyCustomTreeFeatures.createMyCustomBirch().build());
```

##### ❌ Error

```
Attempted to register ID ResourceKey[minecraft:worldgen/configured_feature / minecraft:birch] at different raw IDs (24, 184)! If you're trying to override an item, use .set(), not .register()!
```

#### Way 2 (according to [Fabric Wiki tutorial](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:features#configuring_a_feature))

##### ️ Code

```java
Registry.register(Registry.FEATURE, "birch", Feature.TREE);
Registry.register(BuiltinRegistries.CONFIGURED_FEATURE, "birch", new ConfiguredFeature<>(Feature.TREE, MyCustomTreeFeatures.createMyCustomBirch().build()));
```

##### ❌ Error

```
Attempted to register object net.minecraft.world.level.levelgen.feature.TreeFeature@2aaa5122 twice! (at raw IDs 1 and 61 )
```

#### Way 3 (according to [Fabric Wiki tutorial](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:features#configuring_a_feature) without first line)

##### ️ Code

```java
// Registry.register(Registry.FEATURE, "birch", Feature.TREE);
Registry.register(BuiltinRegistries.CONFIGURED_FEATURE, "birch", new ConfiguredFeature<>(Feature.TREE, MyCustomTreeFeatures.createMyCustomBirch().build()));
```

##### ❌ Error

```
Attempted to register ID ResourceKey[minecraft:worldgen/configured_feature / minecraft:birch] at different raw IDs (24, 184)! If you're trying to override an item, use .set(), not .register()!
```

#### Way 4 (using datapack)

##### ️ File added

File path: `src/main/resources/pack.mcmeta`
File content:

```json
{
    "pack": {
        "pack_format": 9,
        "description": "My mod resources."
    }
}
```

##### ️ File added

File path: `src/main/resources/data/minecraft/worldgen/configured_feature/birch.json`
File content: the original JSON code of the vanilla birch tree configured feature, but with a slight modification of the trunk height.

##### ❌ Does not work

Changes are not applied, nothing happens. I think this is due to the fact that my mod's datapack has a **lower priority** than the vanilla datapack, but I don't know how to fix it.

### My system Info

Minecraft version: `1.18.2`
Mappings: `Parchment`
Parchment mappings version: `2022.11.06`
Fabric API version: `0.76.0+1.18.2`
Fabric loader version: `0.14.24`
Fabric loom version: `1.4-SNAPSHOT`
Java version: `17`
Gradle version: `8.4`
OS: `Windows 10`